# Echoprint not recognizing a single song

Tags: ios, audio-fingerprinting, shazam

> Echoprint “listens” to audio on a phone or on your computer to figure out what song it is. It does so very fast and with such good accuracy that it can identify very noisy versions of the original or recordings made on a mobile device with a lot of interference from outside sources.

I compiled the iOS example provided on the website. So far so good.
Sadly, Echoprint failed to recognize any song via the iPhone's microphone (recording time up to 1 minute).

On the other hand, it *was* capable of recognizing songs by "uploading" them directly from the iPhone's media library.

Any idea, what the problem could be?

Comment: Hi. Did you find out a solution for this? Because i seem to be stuck in about the same issue.

Comment: No. I'm sorry. Dropped the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echo print is not intended to work over the air. At least not with the given configuration. You can adapt the code, focus on the matching functions (best_match), to get some results for over-the-air configuration. The actual best_match function returns a song only if it is really close to the reference, which won't happened with songs recorded with the microphone of your phone.  Also consider recording a longer segment.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you please post any reference stating that fact from their website? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I know this code pretty well, trust me the fingerprin is not very performant with noisy environments and if you read the code in fp.py you will see you get a match only if the query and the reference are very close. You may not find this information on the web site. You should rather read the discussions on their google discussion group if you want to see what can of limitations previous users have encountered.

Comment: Ok. I guess you are right. Can you recommend any alternatives to echoprint? Something to work like Shazam?

Comment: Unfortunately I do know any open source audio fingerprint solution that works fine with noisy environment. But I I sits you can get echo print working if :1you take long segment of audio and 2 you rewrite a matching function less sensitive than the one given by echonest. But if you find a good library for over the air recognition please let me know. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the sampling rate at which the song is being recorded. If it's at 8 kHz it probably won't work; it has to be at least a minimum of 11 kHz.

Comment: Those were mp3s of really high rate.